# exception Error in parcing text file

Tags: java, parsing, exception, inheritance, text-files

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
printHeading(); 

    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nupur\\workspace\\Project2\\src\\EmployeesIn.dat")) ;
    System.out.println("New Employee added: Pryce, Lane");
    System.out.println("New Wages: ");
    while(file1.hasNextLine())
    {
          double total =0;
          String line=file1.nextLine();
          Scanner lineData = new Scanner(line);     
          String name = lineData.next().trim();
          int comma = name.indexOf(',');
          String last = name.substring(0, comma);
          String first = lineData.next().trim();
          char status = (lineData.next().trim()).charAt(0);
          double wage = Double.parseDouble((lineData.nextLine().trim()));
```

It gives me this error: New Wages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.00Baird,   Joey h 7.50Kinsey,  Paul h 8.00Olson,   Margaret                        s 15000Campbell,    Peter           s 20000Draper,  Donald s 40000Sterling, Roger s 45000Cooper,    Bertram             s 50000"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Project2.main(Project2.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all very messy.

How about you do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    printHeading(); 

    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nupur\\workspace\\Project2\\src\\EmployeesIn.dat")) ;
    System.out.println("New Employee added: Pryce, Lane");
    System.out.println("New Wages: ");
    while(file1.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("Wage = " + file1.nextLine().replaceAll("[\\D]", "")) //replace all non-digit characters with blank
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by blank space?

Comment: @NupurPatel `String blankSpace = "" `

Comment: Sorry still not getting.

Comment: @NupurPatel it will replace all letters like `a`, `b`, or `c` with nothing. It will, in layman terms, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse a String that does not contain a double in your last line. Print the output of what you are actually trying to parse to track down your error.

Answer (score 0):

You try to parse "5.00Baird,   Joey h 7.50Kinsey,  Paul h 8.00Olson,   Margaret                        s 15000Campbell,    Peter           s 20000Draper,  Donald s 40000Sterling, Roger s 45000Cooper,    Bertram             s 50000" as an double.

Because this is not a number you get the exception.